# How to convert an YYYY-MM-DD date to YYYY-MM date

Tags: sql, teradata

In SQL. How to convert a column A from (YYYY-MM-DD) to (YYYYMM)? I want to show the dates in YYYYMM format instead of YYYY-MM-DD.

Data type is TIMESTAMP. Using Teradata Studio 15.10.10.

Comment: what's the data type of column A?...and what DBMS

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the error?

Comment: With removing the `-`s.

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Comment: SQL is a language standard, but each RDBMs implements it very differently - especially true of any date functions, please specify which database you are referring to.

Comment: and "convert" like what? for displaying as a string? to store in another table column? to replace the original value?

Comment: The question remains, which dbms are you using? (In ANSI SQL YYYY-MM-DD is not a timestamp value.)

Comment: See: because you didn't tag your DBMS, we have 3 next-to-useless answers that guessed other DBMS and got it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

For Teradata either use

```
to_char(tscol, 'YYYYMM') -- varchar result
```

or

```
extract(year from tscol) * 100 + extract(month from tscol) -- integer result
```

Answer (score 5):

In Teradata you can format dates pretty much at will.  To get YYYYMM, you would use

```
select <your date> (format 'yyyymm') (char(6))
```

Your date column needs to be actual date for this, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 functions you'll need.

MONTH() function. Returns the MONTH for the date within a range of 1 to 12 ( January to December). It Returns 0 when MONTH part for the date is 0.

YEAR() function. Returns a 4 digit YEAR.

CONCAT() function is used to concatenate two or more strings together.

So here's an example of combining the 3 functions.

SELECT CONCAT(YEAR('1969-02-18'),MONTH('1969-02-18'))

or you can do it in one with

select DATE_FORMAT('1969-02-18','%Y%m')

So to answer your question if it is referring to column A, you can use

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A,'%Y%m')

SQL Fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/48362

Comment: "Syntax error: Data Type "A" does not match a defined type name"

Comment: I tested with 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( A,  '%Y%m' ) 
FROM table.

My `A` is timestamp - perhaps test MONTH() or YEAR() individually.

Answer (score -3):

You can use DATEPART to get the year and month parts of the date, cast to a varchar, pad and the concaternate.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) 
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) 

SELECT CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())  AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())  AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.